# React: How to get children component instances?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a few weeks learning Reactjs, I made a Tabpanel component and its implementation looks like this:

```
<Tabpanel>
  <Tab title="Tab1"><p>Hi!</p></Tab>
  <Tab title="Tab2"><p>World!</p></Tab>
</Tabpanel>
```

The component Tabpanel just read the *props* of the dummy *Tab* component and on render creates a *Tabimpl* component which has a state, *Tabpanel* expose methods to control the tabs like `disableTab(index)` and `setTabTitle(index,title)`, I was ok but then my boss suggested that those methods should be on the tab itself, this way when someone uses the component the implementations may look like:

```
<Tabpanel>
  <Tabimpl ref={tab1} title="Tab1"><p>Hi!</p></Tab>
  <Tabimpl title="Tab2"><p>World!</p></Tab>
</Tabpanel>
```

And then to change the tab's title:

```
tab1.setTitle("Changed!");
```

But I can't find a way to access that *Tab* instance from *Tabpanel* to change the *Tab* label when *Tab* state changes, because *Tab* labels are on *Tabpanel*. `props.children` are not instances of Tab. I know I can send a prop with the array of Tabs:

```
<Tabpanel tabs={tabs_array}/>
```

But that sintax is less intuitive due to having to declare the tabs in any other part of the code. Is there a way to do what i want?

Comment: are you sure that you are saving instance correctly why don't you save it like thi ref={ref => this.tab1= ref} not like  ref={tab1}  but

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve, but your entire state should be contained inside `TabPanel`. Then make your tabs dumb components that render based on props sent by TabPanel

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the children and add the refs to the `Tabimpl` component

```
class Tabpanel extends React.Component {
   tabimplrefs = {};
   render() {
      return React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
         return React.cloneElement(child, {
               ref: (ref) => this.tabimplrefs[child.props.title] = ref
         });
      })
   }
}
```

Comment: So I cannot access to the original *Tab* instance only by having the `props.children`?

Comment: you can, but using React.Children.map is the right way to map over the children

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to create `tab1` by `const tab1 = React.createRef()`.